# Macbook Air Hardware Requirement for Android Development?

Tags: android

I want to buy a Macbook Air 2013 for Android and J2EE development, but the Macbook Air specs are an i5 processor, 4GB ram, and a 128GB SSD. So my question is: will this be good enough for development?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you buy 8GB of RAM because you may need to run an emulator. Furthermore, Android Studio also needs a lot of RAM too. Usually, while I code, I also open a web browser in order to search Android Development materials. So I recommend at least 8GB of RAM or 32 GB for fast working and future support

Answer (score 3):

I have a MacBook Air 2012 with 4GB of Ram. It worked well to run Eclipse and Android Studio. It's enough for development, and 8GB is better :)

Answer (score 1):

The environment you have is good enough to run the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) (i.e. Eclipse + Android plugin). However, the default emulator that comes with ADT would run slow and may be choppy. But, as an alternative to this, you can use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) which allows to run Android as a VirtualBox VM, which is much faster than the Android emulator. Also it has an Eclipse plugin, which works great. You will have to download and install [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for this.

**Source:** I have a Linux laptop (Dell) with 4 GB Ram, i5 processor (first generation) and 500Gb (non SSD) Harddisk which I bought in 2009, and I do Android development actively on it :).

About J2EE, if you are planning to use it using IBM Websphere Server, then I suspect that your configuration might be slow. If you are going to use Tomcat, then it might work. I cannot be sure about this as I have never tried it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those specs will be fine for Android Studio or Eclipse. However, if you want to run an emulator, you may find a different computer or more RAM easier to work with.

Comment: Why is my question getting voted down? I've run both IDE's with these specs and never ran into problems.